# Save data asynchronously php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Today one of my client required that he need to save the form data to the server asynchronously **when it CHANGES**

ex :

i have a form for filling the user details ,including text box,select,radio,check etc...

so when i change a value in text box i need to save them back to server.

is there any libraries or something available on php that i can use ?

*Please note i know what is ajax,but still i need to code so much manually,also i care re-usability. Thats why i am asking for a library.*

**Edit**

I know jQuery,Js,Ajax etc ..but my idea is different ...

say that

```
<input type="text" class="dataBinder[name]" id="cname" name="name" />
<input type="checkbox" class="dataBinder[agree_me]" id="agree_me" name="agree_me" />
```

sure i can do

```
 $("#cname").event(function(){

 var is_changed = true; ///check for changes if any

if(is_changed)
{

//send to the server
}

});
```

**BUT I AM SEARCHING FOR A LIBRARY THAT CAN DO THIS AUTOMATICALLY**

ex:

```
//assume a library dataMapper

var myForm = $("#myForm"); //get the form

myForm.dataMapper({

"server" :"serverUrl/someFunc.php"
//may be some other kind of option too
});
```

**someFunc.php** on server

```
dataMapper DM = new dataMapper();

$changes = DM->get_data(); //a function that which give the changes

return $changes
```

the values is from `dataBinder[name]` from

```
<input type="text" class="dataBinder[name]" id="cname" name="name" />
```

`var_dump($changes);` gives

```
array(3) {
  ["changes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cname"]=>
    string(15) "my-changed-name"
    ["agree"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  ["time"]=>
  string(6) "720124"
  ["form"]=>
  string(6) "formId"
}
```

I am sure there may be lot of questions about the developer ,but i am just searching if any because i dont want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Try jQuery. It will be ok on almost any browser.
PS: Pls write down what exactly do you want to be done, using ajax request for some job is too undefined ;-)

Comment: he wants the value saved on field change, not on submit?

Comment: And what if the user has javascript disabled?

Comment: @ftom2 exactly .. when it changes it need to save ..

Comment: jQUery's ajax functions should do the trick for you.  I probably wouldn't worry about the javascipt being disabled use case other than to perhaps have a message on the screen asking the user to enable javascript which can be hidden if javascript is active.  This is probably a tiny use case for most web apps.

Comment: You display a div of 800x600 that says enable javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir , but i am familiar with jQuery ,may be i am asking the question wrong way.If i used jQuery still i need to call ajax functions to save the changes ...i am asking about a configurable plugin/library that which realise the change and send to ther server and process in a temporary table...

Comment: funny the "when it CHANGES" is capitalized and stressed and still people don't read that part.. As to the library question, I don't know of any, but building something like this is absolutely not that difficult.

Comment: @Luceos hehe..i dnt knw what u mean [bcause i dnt knw english much] ..but i am searching if there is such things available .. :D

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a data-save-ajax attribute in every input element you need and add the ajax page as a value. Now you create one jQuery (or whatever ajax javascript you prefer) and write an on-change event handler that saves the values to the data-save-ajax link.

Something like this:

```
jQuery("[data-save-ajax]").change( function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: jQuery(this).attr("data-save-ajax"),
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            newvalue: jQuery(this).val()
        }
    });
});
```

Things to consider is the load this will be generating. Best is to use an event handler when losing focus. Or if you prefer on-change, then perhaps a few milliseconds before starting to  ajax the changes.

The data-save-ajax link will ofcourse be a php page that checks the session and saves the data to the database based on the url. You can use .htaccess (or other) rewriting to let your php know what input you are using.

For instance a data-save-ajax url of `/ajax/text/name` will be rewritten to `/ajax/index.php`.

I once wrote an ajax updater like this, it's easily built and you can update or re-use it easily anytime you have need of it.

Comment: Sure ..thanks for the help .. i need something globally ,so that i can reuse on my next project too.A combination of php and ajax.

Comment: ummmm well.... if we're using the data-* attributes you would want to use `jQuery(this).data('save-ajax')`. does the same thing... but this is how it should be used.

Comment: hm, data is a nice method, must have missed out on this, thanks @rlemon ! Ah, isn't data just for storing information with a matched element, so it doesn't actually get or set the value of an input element?

Comment: data-* attributes will (one day) be mapped to the element.dataset property / interface (whatever) and jQuery mimics this with .data() - so no it does not change the attributes on the element but a stored property on them. However you are only reading it in this case so there is no difference.

Comment: @rlemon, so jquery.data is a mimic of the data-* attribute.. Difference then is the difference in setting it. When writing html, you can more easily add a data-* attribute than writing the script tags with the jquery.data function to hook into the element.. Nice to know of this though.